# Repeatedly applying a function

Tags: infinite-loop

I have writing a code in order to get pixel values of a image along a line. I want to repeatedly to apply the function to the image to get pixel values along multiple lines. My question is how can create such loop in mathematica.

```
IMGV1 = ImageValue[img, Table[{i, 1111}, {i, 300, 2451, 0.5}]];
IMGV2 = ImageValue[img, Table[{i, 1112}, {i, 300, 2451, 0.5}]];
IMGV3 = ImageValue[img, Table[{i, 1113}, {i, 300, 2451, 0.5}]];
IMGV4 = ImageValue[img, Table[{i, 1114}, {i, 300, 2451, 0.5}]];
IMGV5 = ImageValue[img, Table[{i, 1115}, {i, 300, 2451, 0.5}]];
IMGV6 = ImageValue[img, Table[{i, 1116}, {i, 300, 2451, 0.5}]];
```

Comment: It sounds highly unlikely that you'll do better than a built-in function. What exactly do you want to achieve, and how exactly do you need your output to look like? (Keep [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in mind, by the way.)

Comment: Not sure I completely understand. Can't you just do `{IMGV1,IMGV2,....}=Table[ImageValue[img,Table[{i,j}....]],{j,1111,...}]`?

Comment: @Feyre, Yes, you are right I can create multiple variables with iterated names and assign them with each tuple.

Comment: Have you seen [`ImageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageData.html) and [`ImageTake`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageTake.html)?

Comment: @Feyre. I would do `Evaluate[Array[IMGV, 6]] = Table[ImageValue[img, Table[{i, j} ....]], {j, 1111, ...}]` instead so that OP can indexed variables that can actually be operated on using `Table`, `Map`, etc.

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you asking how to generate the symbol names "IMGV1, .." in a loop?